# Aggregate a fields values from elastic search documents using Kibana to have one value as a final search result

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, kibana, vega-lite, vega

our application log file is defined as a multi-document in elastic search since each document has one line of the log file saved in the message field.

I am now trying to collect all the documents which are indicated in the same log file and go through those documents to read the value of the message field and concatenate them together to have the log file text file

let us assume we have those documents with only one field: "message "
[Documents details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B5AY.png)

I am trying to concatenate the value of message 1 + message 2 to have one final message.

I tried to use the Vega lite version 2.4.0 visualize component using kibana 6.8.1 and I applied this solution

I can now concatenate messages but still I can not add new spaces between them or wrap the final result ...

```
{

 

  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json
  title: Logs

 

  // Define the data source
  data: {
    url: {

 

      // Which index to search
      index: *
      body: {
           size :100,
           sort: {
                "@timestamp": {
                  order: "asc"
                }
              },
            query: {
                 match: {
                  "kubernetes.container_name": "istio-proxy"
                 }
          }
         _source: ["message"]


      }
    }

 

    format: {property: "hits.hits"}
  }
  transform :[{

      aggregate:
      [{
        field:"_source.message",
        op :"sum",
        separator:" ' , ' ",
        as:"msgText"
      }]
     },
     {
     calculate :"'The log is : '+ datum.msgText" ,
     as :"formatted_message"

     }
    ]

 

  mark:{
     type :"text"
  }

  encoding: {
      text:{
      field :"formatted_message",
      type:"nominal",
      fontSize :15,
      linebreak:true
     }
  }
  config:{
      text :{
          fontStyle:"normal",
          color:red
          }
  }
}
```

Can You help me to final the optimal solution for my case or if I can use the vega lite component how can I make a new separator spaces between the messages and wrap the text ?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript instead of a vega-lite transform?
Or what about using vega?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you require but you can combine texts visually with a facet. Combining the text with JavaScript is also easily done.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"id": 1, "index": 1, "message": "this is a test 11111111"},
      {"id": 2, "index": 1, "message": "this is a test 2222222222222"},
      {"id": 3, "index": 1, "message": "this is a test 3333333333333333"},
      {"id": 4, "index": 2, "message": "this is a test 4444444444444444444"},
      {"id": 5, "index": 3, "message": "this is a test 5555555555555555555555"}
    ]
  },
  "spacing": 10,
  "facet": {"row": {"field": "index", "header": null}},
  "spec": {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left"},
    "encoding": {
      "y": {"field": "id", "type": "ordinal", "title": null},
      "text": {"field": "message", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}},
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```